# Conexión a MySQL en Docker desde PHPStorm

Tags: mysql, docker, phpstorm

Estoy tratando de conectar a mi BBDD MySQL de un proyecto con Laravel Sail en Docker. El problema es que desde Sequel Ace no tengo problemas con los datos básicos, localhost, 3306, user + pass pero desde PhpStorm me dice que las credenciales son incorrectas (sail/password). ¿Alguna idea de lo que se me escapa en la configuración?

[image: Configuración]

[image: Error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!!!

Ya que Docker no es propiamente nuestro entorno no podemos conectar directamente, para ello, lo que haremos es ajustar el fichero .env añadiendo la siguiente variable de entorno:

FORWARD_DB_PORT=3307

A partir de ahí, cambiando el puerto de conexión del 3306 al 3307 todo va como la seda...